Add break line in bulleted list
I want to add an empty line in a bulleted list with asciidoc. What I want:

I've try with  + but the empty line does not appear :
* item 1
** item 1-1
** item 1-2 +
 +
* item 2
** item 2-1
** item 2-2
** item 2-3

The solo + creates a line with a '+' character.
How can I force the empty line in my list ?

You can put a non-break space on the second line:
* item 1
** item 1-1
** item 1-2 +
{nbsp}
* item 2
** item 2-1
** item 2-2
** item 2-3

But the "right" way to do this, if it's a piece of formatting that you want in general, is with CSS — i.e. the extra leading happens at the display stage, not in the encoding of the text.

If {blank} can accomplish this as well, I'd use it instead of {nbsp}.
